# Maybe a stupid question: I read about equations in physics but are algorithms not also important?

Tags: algorithms

I wonder if indeed the term "equation" is being used loosely and that algorithms for describing physical reality are also used frequently in physics? Or are algorithms relatively rare? Could it be that algorithms only became more common in physics after computers became generally available?

EDIT: I find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_physics and so perhaps I should have asked, did algorithms in physics predate computers?

Comment: Equations are relations between quantities, algorithms are sets of instructions. How would a set of instructions describe “physical reality”?

Comment: @DavidH: It seems to me that, for example, finding the position of a particle might require an algorithm rather than an equation. There are many cases in computer science where a question can only be answered with an algorithm -- there is not an equation which tells us the shortest path through a DAG as a well-known example.

Comment: @releseabe $\operatorname{argmin}(L,\{a:= (a=a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1},b=a_n) \in V^* : a \text{ is path}\}) $ where $L$ is the length functional is a perfectly valid equation for the shortest path between a and b. You might need an algorithm to calculate the actual result, but the equation is valid without an algorithm and a shortest path exists without someone calculating it. The same is true for physics. You might need an algorithm to simulate a physical problem, but physics itself does not, it just is.

Comment: @mlk: i wonder if in general for every algorithm there is an equation?

Comment: @releseabe That is basically the point I was trying to make. Even just writing something like "x = Result of the algorithm" is technically an equation.

Comment: @mlk: Maybe that is trivially true but i feel like there is a fundamental difference between an algorithm and an equation.

Comment: What they said. However, many equations in physics cannot be solved analytically, and must be approximated by numerical methods. Simple methods may converge too slowly to be practical, or may accumulate so much error that they give wrong results. So good algorithms are important, whether you're studying the gravitational interactions of an n body system, or trying to determine the properties of particles using QCD; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD for some info on the latter.

Comment: The book by Stephen wolfram, *A New Kind of Science*  addresses exactly the question you are asking.